# Pipelining in Architectural Simulators

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture

So I'm studying architectural simulators (mostly, simplescalar) to figure out what really happens in the innards of a microprocessor. One fascinating thing i noticed was that, the entire pipeline was written backwards! That is, in a purely sequential while loop, the writeback stage comes before the issue stage, which comes before the decode stage and so on.

What's the point of this? Let's say the output of a hypothetical fetch() stage is stored in a shared buffer ('latch') that is accessed by the input of the decode() stage. Since its a purely sequential while loop, I don't see a problem where this latch/buffer will be overwritten. However, answers to questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955154/mips-pipeline-simulator-using-scoreboarding): claim that simulating the pipeline in reverse somehow avoids this 'problem'? Some insight/guidance in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Simplescalar very well, but I've seen this done in other architectural simulators.

The outer loop of the pipeline is supposed to represent one cycle of the processor. Imagine this is the first cycle and--for simplicity--the front end has a width of one. What would happen if each stage were to be executed in the order of `fetch` to `commmit`?

```
cycles 1
- fetch: instruction 1 (place it in fetch/decode latch)
- decode: instruction 1 (place it in decode/rename latch)
- rename: instruction 1 (place it in rename/dispach latch)
- dispatch: instruction 1 (place it in issue queue)
- issue: instruction 1
etc...
```

You haven't simulated anything useful here as this isn't a pipeline. What happens when the loop executes each stage in the order of `commit` to `fetch`?

```
cycle 1
- issue: noop
- dispatch: noop
- rename: noop
- decode: noop
- fetch: instruction 1 (place it in fetch/decode latch)

cycle 2
- issue: noop
- dispatch: noop
- rename: noop
- decode: instruction 1 (place it in decode/rename latch)
- fetch: instruction 2 (place it in fetch/decode latch)
```

It's not a very complicated idea, but it helps to simplify the simulator.